# rich:extendedDataTable disable column drag and drop

Tags: css, jsf-2, datatable, richfaces

I need to disable column drag and drop feature of richfaces [extendedDataTable](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable) component. Demo source code is sufficient to see that it has functionality of ordering the columns, but due to some design reasons, we do not want to allow users to manipulate order of columns.

Is there any way by CSS or overwriting JS function calls of richfaces to disable this feature?

**Edit:** Richfaces version is 4.3.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured out the solution by peeking in richfaces javascript functions. Posting it here:
Paste below javascript call at the end of page using extendedDataTable. This should disable column ordering functionality.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    RichFaces.ui.ExtendedDataTable.prototype.reorder = function (event) {};
    RichFaces.ui.ExtendedDataTable.prototype.beginReorder = function (event) {};
    RichFaces.ui.ExtendedDataTable.prototype.overReorder= function(event) {};
    RichFaces.ui.ExtendedDataTable.prototype.outReorder= function(event) {};
    RichFaces.ui.ExtendedDataTable.prototype.endReorder= function(event) {};
    RichFaces.ui.ExtendedDataTable.prototype.cancelReorder= function(event) {}; 
</script>
```